Finding the length of base of an isoceles triangle
I'm a middle-school student. While I was solving some geometry problems, I've come across one that I couldn't solve which is the following: ABC Is an isoceles triangle such that AB=AC and the angle. Let [AD] be an altitude of the triangle ABC so that its area is 11,5cm²,and the angle ACD=65°. What is the value of BC? The only information that I could conclude is that AD×BC=23 by knowing the area of the triangle, but nothing else as I have no clue how I can make use of the given angle,so any help or hint is much appreciated

If you know trigonometry the answer is straightforward. But trigonometry is (probably) not in your middle school curriculum. You can probably figure out what you need from the wikipedia page on trigonometry. (Another question you asked here suggests the trigonometric answer.)

Well I have learned sin,cos and tan of 30°,45°,and 60° angles, but that doesn't help in this case as I see

I can't quite tell exactly what information you have from the question. Is it just the angle at $C$ and the area? (Together with knowing that $AB=AC$, this is enough to get $BC$, but I'm not sure how you'd do that without trig). One thing you could do is draw the triangle as accurately as you can (you'll need a protractor) and measure $BC$, but I'm not sure if that's what your teacher is after!

Assuming that your teacher is not deranged, what is your teacher's intent?  What prior training have you been given that might be relevant?  Exactly what lessons were you taught from (for example) the solved problems, worked examples, and theorems, from (for example) the last few weeks, leading up to this problem, that might be pertinent?

Well, I learned Pythagoras, intercept theorem,angle bisector theorem,similar triangles, and the cos,sin and tan of the 30°,45° and 60°angles  in a right triangle as I said earlier, that's it

@Karl As other comments and answers show, you need a calculator to find (approximate) values of the trigonometric functions for other angles.

I'm explaining this in a way I think you'll understand. $$\angle ACD=\angle ABD=65°\text,CD=BD\\\text{(ABC is isoceles, altitude drawn from non equal vertex bisects the opposite side)}$$
Then $$\tan \angle ACD=\frac{AD}{CD}\implies CD=\frac{AD}{\tan\angle ACD}\\\implies CD+BD=2CD=BC=2\frac{AD}{\tan \angle ACD}\\\implies AD=BC×\frac{\tan\angle ACD}{2}=BC×\frac{\tan 65°}{2}$$
But $$AD×BC=23 \implies BC×\frac{\tan 65°}{2}×BC=23\\\implies BC^2=\frac{46}{\tan 65°}\\\implies BC=\sqrt{\frac{46}{\tan 65°}}$$
How to do it in without calculators
Approximating $\tan 65°$ at your level can be done using this method (works nicely for bigger angles between $0°$ to $90°$
$\tan x°≈\frac{10+x}{100-x}=\frac{75}{35}≈2.14$
Divide $46$ by $2.14$ to get $21.5$.
Finally find square root by long division method upto two decimal places to get $4.63$

Its based on 11th higher seconary .If you won't understand ,don't strain , leave it free karl

Click on the link to view my detailed solution

How is $\tan 5°=\frac{π}{36}$?

Gwen ,See for smaller angles , tan theta can be written as theta( but be careful,  it should be in radian)

Is it clear now , reply

Still you're using the wrong formula
$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$

Gwen , your answer is correct,  but standing in midway , please complete it

My new answer is modified with high accuracy

If tye answer helpful , please upvote so that i too can upvote for others, now i won't have much points
